# JQuery & Fancybox clicking image to open a new page/link (Update existing code)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink, fancybox

Good morning,

Iv got a page that currently opens an event image when users land on our main page, this code was already in place and I am simply trying to add in a link to an event we are hosting. (Modify the code) I have been trying to use .wrap and "content" along with a few other things I found on here, however I am unable to modify the code correctly. (When I have made attempts the page will simply quit appearing, so I know there is an error) I am not to familiar with java/fancybox so any help with modifying this current code would be greatly appreciated!

Here is what I currently have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function(){


        jQuery.fancybox({
            'autoScale'         : false,
            'width'             : 783,
            'height'            : 700,
            'autoScale'         : false,
            'transitionIn'          : 'elastic',
            'transitionOut'         : 'none',
            'type'              : 'iframe',
            'titlePosition'         : 'inside',
            'overlayColor'          : '#fff',
            'href'              : '/img/treeofdreams.jpg'
        });

});

</script>
```

PS I tried to even just change the height on the iframe to add in the following below the image:

```
For more details visit our FaceBook page: <a href="url">Click Here</a>
```

However it appears the iframe doesn't want to share more real estate below!

Thank you,

Comment: could you confirm the version of fancybox?

Comment: Sorry about that it is: 1.3.4

Comment: Another question, are you initially opening an iframe (an external page) or an image? ... then from there you want to click something (the image if any or the title) and open another page? ... if so, the new page opens in fancybox or in another window/tab?

Comment: I have the current script above being called out via php include. Once a user types in our url it loads the script off the main page and pops-up the Image (Event flyer), from there Id want them to be able to click on the (IMAGE) to redirect them to another page. (New page/tab)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to add a link to the image that is shown in fancybox, then `.wrap()` method is the way to go, however you may need to know exactly what *selector* you need to target and wrap it within the `onComplete` (v1.3.4) callback

So try this code :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    jQuery.fancybox({
        autoScale: false,
        width: 783, // or whatever needed
        height: 700, 
        transitionIn: 'elastic',
        transitionOut: 'none',
        // type: 'iframe', // you don't need this for images
        titlePosition: 'inside',
        overlayColor: '#fff',
        href: '/img/treeofdreams.jpg', // the URL of the image
        title: "the title", // you may need this
        onComplete: function () {
            jQuery("#fancybox-img").wrap(jQuery("<a />", {
                href: "http://facebook.com/", // the URL to open after clicking the image
                target: "_blank", // opens in a new window/tab
                title: "go to facebook" // optional, shows on mouse hover
            }))
        }
    });
}); // ready
```

**Notice** `#fancybox-img` is the *selector* ID of the fancybox image.

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mbfv41tv/1/)**

**Note**: this is for fancybox v1.3.4

Comment: That actually made the flyer open much nicer then what was there, the link part isn't working, I try clicking everywhere but no go. I see it also added a black title box below the image being displayed which is pretty nice. - Forgive my (not knowing) but for the .wrap to work can you explain what <a />" is?

Comment: Does the jsfiddle demo work for you? didn't you forget to place a `comma` to separate each API option (a comma after the option preceding the `onComplete` option)? Regarding the `<a />` (which is the same as writing `<a></a>`) is the element that we are creating and wraps the fancybox image. Make sure you don;t have sybtax errors.

Comment: I believe everything looks correct, I was trying to post what I have, pretty much the same as above. Just edited the facebook URL to our event. comma's all look good. I don't see any errors being displayed - The JSFiddle does work hmmm am I missing a file?

Comment: The following is being called on in the head prior:
jquery.js?ver=1.11.0
jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.2.1
jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js?ver=3.9.1
jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js?ver=3.9.1'

I ran the code in JSFIDDLE using my js version and it didn't let me switch out that file and see if that fixes it!

Comment: Alright, so I copy/pasted the code I had in my file into JSFIDDLE and it works fine on there... I am going to assume something is off on my files above. I updated my jquery to 1.8.3 no change there. The page is only calling out those four scripts in the head.

Comment: For anyone trying this with version 2.x of fancybox you will want to replace the use of onComplete: with afterShow:, the selector is .fancybox-image instead of #fancybox-img.